# .JS form not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, safari

I have a form in an iframe that submits information to an MLS IDX and shows the properties. The form works great on Chrome and Mozilla, but when using Safari it just reloads the page in a new window instead of showing the results page. I copied the .js and form from the IDX website and do not know anything about .js. The page actually targets a remote .js file and also has .js on the actual page. The page is located at [mariaraymer.com/test1.html](http://mariaraymer.com/test1.html)

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Update 2: Noticed in Safari quickly goes to second page after submit then returns to original URL - Url of page is http://mlssearch.topproduceridx.com/system/safari.asp?url=. Page has this javscript. Page looks to be dedicated to safari as it does not go to a page like this for chrome or firefox.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('test_cookie=1') < 0) {
        var name = 'test_cookie', div = document.getElementById(name), iframe = document.createElement('iframe'), form = document.createElement('form');
        iframe.name = name;
        iframe.src = 'javascript:false';
        div.appendChild(iframe);
        form.action = location.toString();
        form.method = 'POST';
        form.target = "_parent";
        div.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
    else {            

         if (location.search.indexOf('https://') > 0)
            top.location.href = location.search.replace('?url=https://','http://');
         else if (location.search.indexOf('http://') > 0)
            top.location.href = location.search.replace('?url=http://','http://');  

    }

},
10); 
</script>
```

Update: Error in Chrome Console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SwapPriceRange is not defined
3extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:43:13)
```

Moved Code around and received this error:

```
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:43:13)
test1.html:1 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.mariaraymer.com/".
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:43:13)
```

Here is the remote .js code:

```
//***************THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS ARE USED THROUGHOUT************
function openWin(url,windowName,options){
var WindowHandle=window.open(url,windowName,options);
WindowHandle.focus();
}

function openWinFormSubmit(frm,frmaction,url,windowName,options){
frm.submit();
var WindowHandle = window.open(url,windowName,options);
document.location = frmaction;
WindowHandle.focus();
}

var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
var ie=document.all

function showSpan(spanID,thetext){
    if (ie) eval("document.all."+spanID).innerHTML=thetext
    else if (ns6) document.getElementById(spanID).innerHTML=thetext
}
function hideSpan(spanID){
    if (ie) eval("document.all."+spanID).innerHTML=' '
    else if (ns6) document.getElementById(spanID).innerHTML=' '
}

function getElementBy(elemTag){
var elem = document.getElementById (elemTag);
if (elem)
    return elem;
var elems = document.getElementsByName (elemTag);
if (elems.length > 0)
    return elems[0];
return null;
}

function toggleOpenCloseElem(elemName){
    var elem = getElementBy (elemName);
    if (!elem)
        return;
    if (elem.style.display == "")
        elem.style.display = "none";
    else
        elem.style.display = "";
}

function toggleOpenElem(elemName){
    var elem = getElementBy (elemName);
    if (!elem)
        return;
    else
        elem.style.display = "";
}

function toggleCloseElem(elemName){
    var elem = getElementBy (elemName);
    if (!elem)
        return;
    else
        elem.style.display = "none";
}

function GetCookie(name) { // use: GetCookie("name");
    var thecookie = document.cookie;
    var index = thecookie.indexOf(name + "=");
    if (index == -1) return null;
    index = thecookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1; // first character
var endstr = thecookie.indexOf(";", index);
if (endstr == -1) endstr = thecookie.length; // last character
return unescape(thecookie.substring(index, endstr));
}

function SetCookie(name, value) { // use: SetCookie("name", value);
 document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
}

function testForObject(Id){
    var o = document.getElementById(Id);
if (o){return true;}return false;
}

function setAdminSection(str){
    if(str.length >= 14){
    document.getElementById('AdminSection').style.fontSize = '28px' 
}else{
    document.getElementById('AdminSection').style.fontSize = '36px'
}
document.getElementById('AdminSection').innerHTML=str;
}

//***************THE ABOVE FUNCTION IS USED THROUGHOUT************



//***************THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION IS USED FOR FORM        VALIDATION************
function confirmPrompt(msg,url){
    if(confirm(msg)) 
    document.location = url;
}

function confirmPromptFormSubmit(msg,frm,url){
    if(confirm(msg)){
    frm.submit();
    document.location = url;
    }
}

function validateLength(objTB,maxChar){
    if (objTB.value.length > maxChar){return false;}
return true;
}

function validateEmail(objTB){
    var objRegExp  = /^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2}){0,2})$/i; 
    return objRegExp.test(objTB.value);
}

function validateEmailNonReq(objTB){
    var invalidChars = "*|,\":<> []{}`\';()&$#%";
if (objTB.value.length > 0){
    if (objTB.value.indexOf('@') < 0 || objTB.value.indexOf('.') < 0 ||         objTB.value.length < 5){return false;}
    for (var i = 0; i < objTB.value.length; i++){
       if (invalidChars.indexOf(objTB.value.charAt(i)) != -1){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
return true;
} 

function validateTextBox(objTB){
if (objTB.value==''){return false;}
return true;
}

function validateSelectList(objTB){
    if (objTB.selectedIndex==''){return false;}
return true;
}

function validateNumberTextBoxNonReq(objTB){
    if (isNaN(objTB.value)){return false;}
return true;
}

function validateNumberTextBox(objTB){
if (objTB.value=='' || isNaN(objTB.value)){return false;}
return true;
}

function validateZipCodeTextBoxNonReq(objTB){
    reZip = new RegExp(/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/);    
if (!reZip.test(objTB.value)){return false;}
return true;
}

//***************THE ABOVE FUNCTION IS USED FOR FORM VALIDATION************



//***************THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS ARE USED BY THE PROPERTY COMPARE FEATURE************

function commitCompareList(){
    if(GLOBAL_CompareList != '')        {SetCookie("VAR_CompareList",GLOBAL_CompareList);}
    if(GLOBAL_CompareCount != '')   {SetCookie("CompareCount",GLOBAL_CompareCount);}
}       

function sendToCompare(querystring){
    if (GLOBAL_CompareCount < 2){
    alert('Please check more than 1 listing!');
}else{
    if (GLOBAL_CompareCount > 4){
        alert('Please check no more than 4 listings!');
    }else{
        window.location = "/property/propertycompare.asp?   VAR_CompareList=" + GLOBAL_CompareList + "&CompareCount=" +     GLOBAL_CompareCount + querystring;
    }
}
}

function compareClear(){
    GLOBAL_CompareList = '';
GLOBAL_CompareCount = '';
if(GetCookie('VAR_CompareList') != null && GetCookie('VAR_CompareList') != ""){SetCookie("VAR_CompareList",'');}
if(GetCookie('CompareCount') != null && GetCookie('CompareCount') != ""){SetCookie("CompareCount",'');}
}

function addCompare(obj){
    //the maximum number of listings a user can check to compare
var Max_Number_Properties = 4;

if(obj.checked == true){
    if(GLOBAL_CompareCount == Max_Number_Properties){           
        obj.checked = false;
        alert('You have already chosen ' + Max_Number_Properties + ' properties!');
    }else{
        GLOBAL_CompareList = GLOBAL_CompareList + obj.value;
        GLOBAL_CompareCount = Math.round(GLOBAL_CompareCount) + 1;
    }
}else{
    GLOBAL_CompareCount = Math.round(GLOBAL_CompareCount) - 1;
    GLOBAL_CompareList = GLOBAL_CompareList.replace(obj.value,"");
}
}
    //***************THE ABOVE FUNCTIONS ARE USED BY THE COMPARE TOOL************



//***************THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS ARE USED BY THE eNavigator FEATURE************

//Clears eNavigator Cookies
function eNavigatorClear(){
    if(GetCookie('eNavigator_SearchForm_State') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_SearchForm_State') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_SearchForm_State','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLat') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLat') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLat','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLng') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLng') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_CenterLng','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_ZoomLevel') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_ZoomLevel') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_ZoomLevel','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_MapStyle') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_MapStyle') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_Prev_MapStyle','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_City') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_City') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_City','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_ZipCode') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_ZipCode') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_VAR_ZipCode','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_PropertyTypeCode') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_PropertyTypeCode') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_PropertyTypeCode','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Price') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Price') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Price','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Maximum_Price') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Maximum_Price') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Maximum_Price','')};
if(GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Beds') != null && GetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Beds') != ""){SetCookie('eNavigator_PRM_Minimum_Beds','')}; //KILLS BATHS TOO (don't ask)
}
//***************THE ABOVE FUNCTIONS ARE USED BY eNavigator************
```

This is the .js on the actual page with the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm1(frm) {

        var msg = '';

        if (!validateTextBox(frm.VAR_MLSNumber)) { msg = msg + 'One or More MLS Numbers\n'; }

        if (msg == '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            msg = 'The following field(s) are required:\n\n' + msg + '\n';
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }

    }

    function validateForm2(frm) {

        var msg = '';
        var CityCnt = 0;
        var ZipCnt = 0;

        for (var x = 0; x < frm.VAR_City.length; x++) {
            if (frm.VAR_City.options[x].selected) {
                CityCnt = CityCnt + 1;
            }
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < frm.VAR_ZipCode.length; x++) {
            if (frm.VAR_ZipCode.options[x].selected) {
                ZipCnt = ZipCnt + 1;
            }
        }

        if (CityCnt > 10) { msg = msg + '10 or less Cities\n'; }
        if (ZipCnt > 10) { msg = msg + '10 or less Zip Codes\n'; }

        if (frm.VAR_City.selectedIndex < 0 && frm.VAR_ZipCode.selectedIndex < 0) { msg = msg + 'One or more Cities OR Zip Codes\n'; }

        if (msg == '') {
            toggleOpenCloseElem('searchingTR1');
            return true;
        } else {
            msg = 'The following field(s) are required:\n\n' + msg + '\n';
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function disableFields(selVal) {

        if (selVal == 'COM' || selVal == 'CML' || selVal == 'LND' || selVal == 'IMF' || selVal == 'RSL') {
            if (testForObject('PRM_Minimum_Beds')) {
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_Beds.selectedIndex = -1;
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_Beds.disabled = true;
            }
            if (testForObject('PRM_Minimum_baths')) {
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_baths.selectedIndex = -1;
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_baths.disabled = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (testForObject('PRM_Minimum_Beds')) {
                if (frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_Beds.selectedIndex < 0) {
                    frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_Beds.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_Beds.disabled = false;
            }
            if (testForObject('PRM_Minimum_baths')) {
                if (frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_baths.selectedIndex < 0) {
                    frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_baths.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                frmMain2.PRM_Minimum_baths.disabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (testForObject('PRM_Custom9')) {
            if (selVal != 'IMF' && selVal != 'RNT') {
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom9.selectedIndex = -1;
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom9.disabled = true;
            } else {
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom9.selectedIndex = 0;
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom9.disabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (testForObject('PRM_Custom12')) {
            if (selVal == 'COM' || selVal == '') {
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom12.disabled = false;
            } else {
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom12.checked = false;
                frmMain2.PRM_Custom12.disabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

This is the form

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 class="tableBorder" width=230px>
  <tr>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign=top colspan=0 style="padding:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF;">

        <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=67%>
        <tr>




                <!--td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width=2></td>
                <td class=searchTab align=center><div onClick="document.location.href='http://mlssearch.topproduceridx.com/property/map.asp';">Map</div></td-->


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=0  bgcolor="ffffff">



            <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=2 class="Website_Text" width=100%>


            <form method="get" action="http://mlssearch.topproduceridx.com/property/proplist.asp" name="frmMain2" target="_blank" onSubmit="return(validateForm2(this));">

                <input type="hidden" name="VAR_ShowResultOptions" value="1">            

            <input type="hidden" name="VAR_SearchSource" value="propsearch">

                    <tr>
            <td class="searchPageSectionHeader">Listing Location <font color=FF0000>*</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign=top align=left class="searchPageSectionBG" style="padding-top:8px" nowrap>MLS Number:</td>
</tr>
       <tr>
                    <td><input name="VAR_MLSNumber" size=30 maxlength=38 value=""></td></tr>

          <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">

                    <td nowrap style="padding-top:8px" >Street Address:       </td>
                    </tr>
<tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                    <td width=100%>

                        <input name="PRM_Address" size=30 maxlength=32 value=""><br>

                    </td>

                </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 class="Website_Text">

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="searchPageSectionHeader">Listing Features</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 class="Website_Text" width=80%>



                    <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                        <td>&nbsp;Type:</td>
                        <td colspan=0 width=15px>
                            <select name="PRM_PropertyTypeCode" onChange="javascript:disableFields(this.value); SwapPriceRange(this.value);" class="searchPageSectionBG">
                            <option value="">Any listing type</option>

                                    <option value="RES">Single Family Home</option>

                                    <option value="CND">Townhome or Condo</option>

                                    <option value="IMF">Multi-Family Home</option>

                                    <option value="LND">Lots and Land</option>

                                    <option value="COM">Commercial</option>

                                    <option value="FRM">Farm</option>



                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>





                    <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">

                    </tr>




                    <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                        <td nowrap>&nbsp;Price:</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <select name="PRM_Minimum_Price" id="PRM_Minimum_Price" class="searchPageSectionBG">
<option value="">Any price</option>
<option value="50000">$50,000</option>
<option value="100000">$100,000</option>
<option value="150000">$150,000</option>
<option value="200000">$200,000</option>
<option value="250000">$250,000</option>
<option value="300000">$300,000</option>
<option value="350000">$350,000</option>
<option value="400000">$400,000</option>
<option value="450000">$450,000</option>
<option value="500000">$500,000</option>
<option value="550000">$550,000</option>
<option value="600000">$600,000</option>
<option value="650000">$650,000</option>
<option value="700000">$700,000</option>
<option value="750000">$750,000</option>
<option value="800000">$800,000</option>
<option value="850000">$850,000</option>
<option value="900000">$900,000</option>
<option value="950000">$950,000</option>
<option value="1000000">$1,000,000</option>
<option value="1250000">$1,250,000</option>
<option value="1500000">$1,500,000</option>
<option value="1750000">$1,750,000</option>
<option value="2000000">$2,000,000</option>
<option value="">Any price</option>
                            </select></td></tr>
                            <tr class="searchPageSectionBG"><td align="center">
                            to</td>

                            <td align="left">
                            <select name="PRM_Maximum_Price" id="PRM_Maximum_Price" class="searchPageSectionBG">
<option value="">Any price</option>
<option value="50000">$50,000</option>
<option value="100000">$100,000</option>
<option value="150000">$150,000</option>
<option value="200000">$200,000</option>
<option value="250000">$250,000</option>
<option value="300000">$300,000</option>
<option value="350000">$350,000</option>
<option value="400000">$400,000</option>
<option value="450000">$450,000</option>
<option value="500000">$500,000</option>
<option value="550000">$550,000</option>
<option value="600000">$600,000</option>
<option value="650000">$650,000</option>
<option value="700000">$700,000</option>
<option value="750000">$750,000</option>
<option value="800000">$800,000</option>
<option value="850000">$850,000</option>
<option value="900000">$900,000</option>
<option value="950000">$950,000</option>
<option value="1000000">$1,000,000</option>
<option value="1250000">$1,250,000</option>
<option value="1500000">$1,500,000</option>
<option value="1750000">$1,750,000</option>
<option value="2000000">$2,000,000</option>
<option value="">Any price</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>




                <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">



                        <td nowrap>&nbsp;Bedrooms:</td>
                        <td align="left" >
                            <select name="PRM_Minimum_Beds" id="PRM_Minimum_Beds" class="searchPageSectionBG">
                            <option value="" >Any number</option>
                            <option value="1">At least 1</option>
                            <option value="2">At least 2</option>
                            <option value="3">At least 3</option>
                            <option value="4">At least 4</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;
                        </td>


                        </tr>
                        <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                        <td nowrap>&nbsp;Bathrooms:</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <select name="PRM_Minimum_baths" id="PRM_Minimum_baths" class="searchPageSectionBG">
                            <option value="" >Any number</option>
                            <option value="1">At least 1</option>
                            <option value="2">At least 2</option>
                            <option value="3">At least 3</option>
                            <option value="4">At least 4</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;
                        </td>



                </tr>



                </table>

            </td>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="Website_Text" width=100%>



                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="searchPageSectionHeader">Lot Features</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="Website_Text" width=100%>



                    <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                        <td nowrap>&nbsp;Lot Size (Acres):</td>
                        <td width=100%  color="#7b8283">&nbsp;
                            <select name="VAR_SqFt" class="searchPageSectionBG">

                        <option value="">Any size</option>
                            <option value="0-.49">Less than 0.5</option>
                            <option value=".5-1">0.5 - 1</option>
                            <option value="1-2">1 - 2</option>
                            <option value="2-5">2 - 5</option>
                            <option value="5-10">5 - 10</option>
                            <option value="10.1-1000000">More than 10</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>





                    <tr class="searchPageSectionBG">
                        <td colspan=0 nowrap>

                            <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="Website_Text">
                            <tr>

                                <td class="searchPageSectionBG"><input type=checkbox value=1 name="PRM_Waterfront" > Waterfront&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                            </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>



            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>    

    </td>
</tr>




            <tr>
                <td colspan=0 valign=middle  nowrap align=left >
                    <input type="submit" align="left" value="Search" style="background-color: #ec894d; color: #ffffff; border-color: #ec894d; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" class="button">
                <input type=radio name=PRM_OrderBy style="display:none;" value="pReciprocity ASC, pPrice DESC" Checked>                 </td>
            </tr>

            </table>

            <p>

    </td>
</tr>

</form>


</table>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Firefox and Mozilla? Aren't those the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` as a child of `<table>` The children of `<table>` must be table elements like `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, or `<tr>`. When you give invalid HTML like this, the browser tries to fix it up, and different browsers do this differently. What's happening is that the submit button is not connected to the form properly, so it's not sending to the `action` URL.

Instead of putting the form inside the table, put the table inside the form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://mlssearch.topproduceridx.com/property/proplist.asp" name="frmMain2" target="_blank" onSubmit="return(validateForm2(this));">
    <input type="hidden" name="VAR_ShowResultOptions" value="1">            
    <input type="hidden" name="VAR_SearchSource" value="propsearch">
    <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=2 class="Website_Text" width=100%>
    ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Also, your `<table>` and `</table>` tags aren't matched up properly: you have 8 `<table>` and 9 `</table>`.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try it now. And I meant Chrome and Firefox (-: ... I wonder why it worked on Chrome and Firefox as is, but not Safari. ah I see you said browsers handle the error differently.

Comment: I tried  and problem still persists. I did look at the Chrome console and it shows this error 

    Uncaught ReferenceError: SwapPriceRange is not defined
3extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:43:13)

Comment: You have this in the HTML: `onChange="javascript:disableFields(this.value); SwapPriceRange(this.value);"` but there's no `SwapPriceRange` function in the Javascript. You need to define that function or get rid of the call to it.

Comment: That error is unrelated to submitting the form. I guess it's supposed to do something to the price range menus when you select different listing types.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Updated the question with a url the page quickly redirects to then redirects back to original url. Page does contain javascript as well

Comment: That's something you need to take up with the people who operate the `mlssearch.topproduceridx.com` site.